# More than 1GB memory allocation error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to develop an application which allocates given number of GB's from the RAM. When i try to allocate 1 GB RAM it works fine but, more than 1GB, it crashes.

I am using Windows 7 - 64bit and I have 6 GB RAM (Installed Memory). I develop this application with Qt and I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Code is here:

```
int size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
m_Size = ui.CPUAllocationEntry->text().toInt();


m_Arr =(char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*size*m_Size);
memset(m_Arr, 1, size*m_Size);
if (m_Arr == NULL)
{
    qDebug() << "Pointer Null" << endl;
}
else
    qDebug() << "Pointer NOT null" << endl;

return;
```

And the error is:

> First-chance exception at 0x0F993FD4 (msvcr120d.dll) in ttool.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x0F993FD4 (msvcr120d.dll) in ttool.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

I tried this as an 32-bit application but also 64-bit application and the result was the same. Also i tried /LARGEADRESSAWARE option for the linker. However i could not find a solution.

I know it may be about how much RAM i am using but when i using 3.02GB RAM and try to allocate 2GB, it crashes too.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: `memset` should be under a condition. At least it won't crash and print `Pointer Null`.

Comment: There may not be that much contiguous memory available.

Comment: This might also be a Windows thing, once I wrote an application with a pretty bad memory leak, and when it got above 1GB of ram, it crashed, presumably closed by Windows. This was on Windows 7 -64 bit, with 4GB available in the machine.

Comment: Did you really try to compile as 64-bit ? Obviously it won't work in 32-bit, since the maximum is 2GB of unfragmented memory.

Comment: @ElderBug Yes i tried to compile as 64-bit. Now it allocates but, after the allocation, it stops responding.

Comment: Then you should post your real problem. Nothing you posted here seems to be related to the 64-bit error. How much memory are you allocating ? The system will allow you to allocate more than 6GB, but if you do so it may be **really** slow, so it would seem to hang. Check your total memory usage to be sure.

Comment: @ElderBug i am trying to allocate 2GB. I think it is trivial to know that i shouldn't try to allocate >=6GB's.

Comment: But did you check the total memory usage ? Don't forget that your program share those 6GB with everything else. If this is a total RAM problem, removing any access (the memset) should prevent the hang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your memory is fragmented. You are asking for one big block of 1GB, but no such block is available. There may very well be ten 512MB blocks available, but that's not good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're using the type `int`, which is a 32-bit integer, in a multiplication which causes integer overflow (1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2 produces a negative result with a 32-bit `int`).

You should be using `size_t` instead (presumably your OS is 64-bit whether or not your app is).